# Can't cherry pick (error)

Tags: android, git, github, cyanogenmod, cherry-pick

I'm trying to cherry-pick a commit from *CyanogenMod Github* and having issue, here's more info:

- Commit to cherry-pick: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_lge_bullhead/commit/4c98c8df392dfb305d7ffe5deaf9a2bdf7824037
- Error occurring:

  ```
  error: commit 4c98c8df392dfb305d7ffe5deaf9a2bdf7824037 is a merge but no -m option was given.
  fatal: cherry-pick failed
  ```

  Please help me, my repo is based off CM, has a different branch and is modified for a different ROM.

Answer (score 1):

When cherry-picking a merge commit, you need to specify the mainline. The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

> -m parent-number
>
> --mainline parent-number
>
> Usually you cannot cherry-pick a merge because you do not know which side of the merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows cherry-pick to replay the change relative to the specified parent.

Consider the following commit log:

```
   B - C
  /     \
A--D-E-F-G
```

Now, if you tell git to cherry-pick G, you are telling it: "Take the changes that commit G introduces". But that is ambiguous - in relation to commit C, G introduces changes made in D, E, and F. In relation to commit F, it introduces changes B and C.

To overcome this, you need to specify the mainline argument, which tells git whether C or F should be considered the mainline against which the comparison is done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what should I do now? Do the changes manually or there's more options?

Comment: You should specify the `-m` argument as my answer suggests.

Comment: can I cherry both commits which were merged in that commit?

Comment: I don't think you understand what cherry-picking a merge commit implies. You need to tell git if you want the changes that the commit introduces in relation to commit `54eac05` or commit `8159d23`.

Comment: @Sid Check the edits I made, see if it clears things up.

Comment: The help says "parent number" but your example has "C" and "F" as the parents, how do I convert to this parent number, is F = 1?

Comment: Doing `git show G` (where G is a merge commit) will display a line like this: `Merge: abc123 def456`. The `-m` parameter refers to the order of these commits.